# How can I get the version of Concourse or the fly CLI via the API

Tags: concourse, concourse-fly

I am downloading the `fly` Concourse CLI via the web interface or via the API endpoint: `/api/v1/cli?arch=amd64&platform=darwin`.

Is there a way to get via a similar API endpoint the version of Concourse or of the `fly` CLI?

I am using this in order to compare the existing `fly` CLI that the user has and the one he can download (suggesting him/her an update in case there is a newer version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/api/v1/info` should tell you the version of Concourse (which goes in lockstep with the version of the fly CLI).

Note that the fly cli will warn you if you are using a version of the CLI that's out of sync with the version of Concourse you are targetting.